# Синхронизация доступа к БД из разных процессов

Tags: c#, postgresql

Есть бд, postgreSQL, а так же два процесса написанные на C#, один удаляет и добавляет данные в бд раз в минуту, второй процесс читает из неё несколько сотен раз в минуту. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно синхронизировать доступ к бд?

Comment: Что имеется в виду? что надо синхронизировать и зачем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: БД - многопользовательская система, не надо ничего синхронизировать.

Comment: Если вас волнует неконсистентность данных - используйте транзакции.

Comment: Прочитал, что возникают проблемы, когда совпадают запрос на добавление данных, с запросом на чтение, как то так. Видел, что в запросах используют определённые команды на блокировку бд во время записи,но я использую entity framework core. Как это сделать используя текущий функционал не понятно и так же не ясно, что происходит с запросом на чтение в момент блокировки - встаёт ли он в очередь или просто отклоняется. Извиняюсь за некорректные вопросы, эта тема для меня новая...

Comment: А это читали https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/saving/transactions

Answer (score 0):

Для такого я бы сделал API, чтобы был некий посредник, который сам выполняет команды, а фронт просто дёргает за ниточки и гоняет данные